# Command-line hexidecimal search, find & replace

Tags: command-line, replace, where-clause

I have a file that needs to be examined through Windows Command Line.
There are instances of pre-known hexidecimal values (for example, 02 95) that need to be relayed back to the user onscreen as found, and then I need yet another tool or program to edit this exact same string that has been found.

So in short, I know there is an instance of 02 95, yet I don't know WHERE is it, and I want to replace it. and have all of that information relayed to the user(s).

First post :P

Comment: get linux/mac/proper-OS :P

Comment: At the moment this seems very tedious and I wish to use cmd. If you can tell me what program any of these os's would offer me, and if there's a Windows equivalent, that would be handsome.

Comment: sounds like you should be using text editor, not cmd. Try notepad++ and messing around with encoding.

Comment: Showing us the file contents will help.  Do you want the line number? Do you want to show the entire line? Something else?  What do you want to replace it with?  Give details.

Comment: I resolved this issue, but now I have [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966845/displaying-the-libraried-instances-of-prediefined-strings-within-a-file-in-cmd/)

Answer (score 0):

can you install sed for windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) or install cygwin (http://cygwin.com/install.html) directly

With that, you can easily run the sed command to replace the key words.

```
sed 's/02 95/OTHER/' file
```

Comment: do I understand it as...
"sed" is the program
"'s/02 95/OTHER/'" is what im searching for and "file" is the file to search?

Comment: so if you are not sure the answer, please provide more details about your questions. Give some sample input file will be easy for everyone to understand your request.

Comment: the sed command will search the key word "02 95" and replace by "OTHER" in file of "file".

Comment: Will this work with hex? I'm not trying to replace a regular string of text within a document. I'm trying to edit the hexidecimal values which represent the text within the file.

Comment: Clarify this in your question.  Are you looking for a literal "02 95" that is 5 bytes in length?