# Displaying the "libraried" instances of prediefined strings within a file in CMD

Tags: windows, file, variables, cmd, instance

All commands must be performed in Windows Command Prompt

I have a file data.txt which has several strings in it:

```
gargonxx**stringX**moregargon
gargonargongargongargon
gargon**stringZ**xxgargonxxxx
```

and for this data file, I want to create a "library" file:

```
stringX = informationx
stringY = informationy
stringZ = informationz
```

then create variables in CMD out of the "information" shown in the "library" file,
ONLY of the instances in the data.txt file that match with the library file.

```
varx = string's informationx
```

and then relay this information in the command window.

```
echo varx
```

How do I go about

1. Having CMD recognize the instances that match
2. Relaying the instance's information in the command window

Here are my [LIBRARY and DATA files](http://ge.tt/9s5bkrC1)

Comment: In theory, you could do this in batch, but you will hate it. I would recommend using a different programming language to generate the information, then use a batch file to do the `SET`s.

Comment: What language do you suggest I use? I'm a bit scared of putting my feet in the water :S

Comment: A scripting language is probably appropriate for this task.

Comment: You've supplied a hex dump of a file and a library file which has no correlation to what you have described.  What are we supposed to do with them? :D

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims==" %%a IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO "SET %%a="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (data.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims== " %%L IN (library.txt) DO (
  IF /i "%%a"=="%%L" SET $%%a=%%M&ECHO(%%M
 )
)
ECHO ==== OR =====
SET $

GOTO :EOF
```

use a text editor to create the library file.

This batch matches the instances that match.

Showing the information depends on what you want to do.

With 'data.txt`

```
lineX
lineZ
```

and `library.txt`

```
lineX = informationx
lineY = informationy
lineZ = informationz
```

the above batch showed

```
informationx
informationz
==== OR =====
$lineX=informationx
$lineZ=informationz
```

---

For revised specification

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims==" %%a IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO "SET %%a="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims== " %%L IN (library.txt) DO (
 FINDSTR /i /L "%%L" data.txt >nul
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET $%%L=%%M&ECHO(%%M
)
ECHO ==== OR =====
SET $

GOTO :EOF
```

(same results, except `line` replaced by `string`)

Comment: I edited the question a bit, so you can understand it more. The string is actually mixed in with other stuff.
here are my [data.txt and library.txt](http://ge.tt/9s5bkrC1)